# change text color from directive when innerHTML matches

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page where I am rendering many columns with the help of the ng-repeat.

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-repeat="col in selectedColumn" class="cellHldr ng-status-color">{{lead[col.name]}}</div>
```

Now I have made a directive **ngStatusColor**

```
.directive('ngStatusColor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        compile: function (tElement, tAttributes) {
            return {
                post: function postLink( scope, element, attributes ) {
                    console.log("element",element[0].innerHTML );
                    if(element[0].innerHTML=='Open'){
                        console.log("hellooo");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I need to color the text of that column which has the `{{lead[col.name]}}`like 'open','closed'. Rest should be left as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going the innerHtml way , you can just add a font tag to the inner html to change the color :

```
 if(element[0].innerHTML=='Open'){
       element[0].innerHTML="<font color='red'>"+element[0].innerHTML+"</font>";
 }
```

The angular way to do this would be using `ng-class`.On your `div` which put the following :

```
ng-class="{ 'red': lead[col.name]=='Open', blue: lead[col.name]=='close' }"
```

And create two css classes red and blue:

```
.red {
 color: red;
}

.blue {
 color: blue;
}
```

What this will do this is when it will assign `red` class to your element if the value of `lead[col.name]` becomes 'Open' , Blue if 'Close'.

If you want to get more info about ng-class , I would recommend you to go through this link :[ng-class uses](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

Comment: what else is the procedure if I dont wanna go innerHTML way

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-class for the same.

**CSS**

```
.colorChange {
    color: green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="col in selectedColumn" class="cellHldr ng-status-color" ng-class="lead[col.name] === 'open' ? 'colorChange': 'normalStyle'">{{lead[col.name]}}</div>
```

Will this approach work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(element[0].innerHTML=='Open'){
  element[0].style.color = "red";
}
```